# Dump/save current keymap/layout?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

Is there a way to dump the current keymap / keyboard layout, so it can be loaded on another host with `xmodmap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in the `xmodmap` man page. Try the following switch:

```
   -pke    This  option indicates that the current keymap table should be printed on
           the standard output in the form of expressions that can be  fed  back  to
           xmodmap.
```

Redirect this to a file and Xmodmap can read this file to set the keymap. This only applies when using X. If you need something similar on the console, look at `loadkeys`.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [`xkbcomp`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xkbcomp.1.html) and [`setxkbmap`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/setxkbmap.1.html).